# How to identify an element via XPath when IDs keep changing

Tags: html, xml, xpath, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am using a website, where the values of the elements are changing dynamically every time the elements load. The id's are dynamic and so is the XPath. I don't seem to have any unique identifier to locate the elements. Please advise on the best way to uniquely identify the element every time the page loads.

Here is the example of the XPath when the page loads for the first time:

```
.//*[@id='isc_HY']/table/tbody/tr/td
```

the same element when I do another run is as follows:

```
.//*[@id='isc_IP']/table/tbody/tr/td
```

There are several other elements on the page that looks like the above elements.

For example, there is an element with the following XPath that I don't need:

```
.//*[@id='isc_I2']/table/tbody/tr/td
```

**Here is the HTML information for the same:**

```
<div id="isc_HY" style="position: relative; display: inline-block; box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; vertical-align: top; visibility: inherit; z-index: 204195; cursor: pointer;" eventproxy="isc_OBTabBarButtonChild_9">
 <table width="68px" height="38px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <tbody>
 <tr>
 <td class="OBTabBarButtonChildTitleOver" valign="center" nowrap="true" align="right" onfocus="isc_OBTabBarButtonChild_9_label.$47()" tabindex="-1">Item Pricing</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
<div id="isc_I0" class="OBTabBarButtonChildTopOver" onscroll="return isc_OBTabBarButtonChild_9.$lh()" style="position: absolute; left: 208px; top: 0px; width: 96px; height: 38px; z-index: 204194; box-sizing: border-box; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer; outline-style: none;" tabindex="4914" onblur="if(window.isc)isc.EH.blurFocusCanvas(isc_OBTabBarButtonChild_9,true);" onfocus="if(event.target!=this)return;isc.EH.focusInCanvas(isc_OBTabBarButtonChild_9,true);" role="tab" eventproxy="isc_OBTabBarButtonChild_9">
<div id="isc_I1" onscroll="return isc_OBTabBarButtonChild_10.$lh()" style="position: absolute; left: 319px; top: 0px; width: 59px; height: 38px; z-index: 204213; box-sizing: border-box; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer; outline-style: none;" tabindex="-1" onblur="if(window.isc)isc.EH.blurFocusCanvas(isc_OBTabBarButtonChild_10_label,true);" onfocus="if(event.target!=this)return;isc.EH.focusInCanvas(isc_OBTabBarButtonChild_10_label,true);" role="label" eventproxy="isc_OBTabBarButtonChild_10">
```

**I am looking to click on the "Item Pricing" text.**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Kmeixner i am trying to locate the elements and click on it. I need help in trying to find the best way to uniquely identify the element every time the page loads.

Comment: Identify invariant content such as might be used to label the targeted value, and then write an XPath based on the invariant, associated content.  Sorry for such an abstract answer, but you've not provided enough detail to receive a concrete answer.

Comment: @kjhughes what other information are you looking for, i can try and provide that. Thank you.

Comment: Show specific HTML that includes a targeted value, say $1.23, and an associated label, say "Price".   State that you want the value next to the "Price" label.  We get that you can't use ID's.  You have to show how the content, at some level, has enough invariance for your request to be viable.

Comment: @kjhughes thank you for the info, i have included the relevant code for the HTML and i am looking for the "Item Pricing" text and click on it. Please advise if you need anything else. appreciate your help.

Comment: `//td[. = 'Item Pricing']` will select the table cell whose contents equals the string "Item Pricing".

Comment: @kjhughes dude that worked, i can locate the element, was about to rip my last few hair out of my skull. thank you for saving my hair.

Comment: You're welcome.  I added the money comment as an answer, if you'd care to [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select a table cell whose contents equals a string such as "Item Pricing" via the following XPath:

```
//td[. = 'Item Pricing']
```